# How to retrieve value from description field of active directory and display it in textbox using infopath

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, active-directory

I used `getUSerProfileByName` web service to retrieve basic info of current user from active directory but I am unable to retrieve value of description field.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default `Description` field is not mapped to User Profile properties,  to find the default mapped properties ,check the full list at [Default user profile property mappings in SharePoint Server 2013 from AD DS attribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510.aspx)

So now you need first to add new map property at user Profile for description attribute to can find it via `getUSerProfileByName` at InfoPath as the following  :

**Add a new mapped property**

- In central Administration > Manage Service application > Click on User Profile Sync Service> People>  Manage User Properties  > New Property.
- Select Type String  (multi value) > and Select Attribute Description.

**Then retrieve user profile properties with Description field via InfoPath  as the following :**

- First, you should create a data connection from SOAP web Service at Data Tab

[image]

- Select Receive Data and next then add UserProfileService web service URL
  via `http://yoursitename/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDl`
- Select Get `GetUserProfileByName` > Continue wizard .
- Now at `GetUserProfileByName` connection, you should find Description field .

To add it to infopath form continue at [Using InfoPath and the Web service GetUserProfileByName](http://eimagine.com/using-infopath-and-the-web-service-getuserprofilebyname/)

Comment: Hi @M.Ali Is this solved your issue :) ? if no please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification , if yes please set it as an answer and upvote it as mentioned at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour :)